# Field `state` does not exist in Odoo 13

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

`view.xml`

```
<record id="fsm_order_form" model="ir.ui.view">
<field name="name">fsm.order.form</field>
<field name="model">fsm.order</field>
<field name="inherit_id" ref='fieldservice.fsm_order_form'/>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
    <xpath expr="//notebook/page[@name='planning_page']/group" position="after">
        <field name="planning_ids">
            <tree string='Planning'>
                <field name="employee_id"/>
                <field name="role_id"/>
                <field name="start_datetime"/>
                <field name="end_datetime"/>
                <field name="allocated_hours"/>
                <field name="wage"/>
            </tree>
        </field>

        <group>
            <group class="oe_subtotal_footer oe_right" name="planning_hours">
                <field name="planned_hours" widget="float_time"/>
                <field name="currency_id" invisible='1'/>
                <field name="planned_labour_cost" class="oe_subtotal_footer_separator" widget='monetary'
                        options="{'currency_field': 'currency_id'}"/>
            </group>
        </group>
    </xpath>
</field>
```

`__manifest__.py`

```
'depends': ['base','web','mail','dms','project_stock_request','business_requirement','stock_request_customization','bi_job_cost_estimate_customer','planning','repair','project','quality_control','project_task_material','sale_timesheet','hr_timesheet','fieldservice','maintenance','mrp','maintenance_plan','bi_job_cost_estimate_customer'],
```

I'm getting Field `state` does not exist in Odoo 13 when upgrading the module. This error was never raised before and code is not not even changed now.
The module `fieldservice` is already in dependency list in `__manifest__.py`. The model `fsm.order` is extended in another custom module adding the field *state*.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "The model fsm.order is extended in another custom module adding the field state."? Because making this other custom module a dependency should work.

Comment: @CZoellner What I mean is the state is added by another custom module , since we have inherited the base model, it is not needed to make the custom module a dependency . Even I added that , nothing changes . In face that custom module also show the same error.